# Adding children to a canvas giving me lag

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, user-controls

**Situation/Problem**

I'm attempting to create a small game which needs me to add a X amount of controls to a canvas.

When the amount of controls is low, it all works perfectly. The control gets add and after that there's a storyboard being triggered that changes the opacity from 0 to 1 in .5 sec. However, when there's more then like 30/40 controls the program "lags" and the first .2 sec of the storyboard are being "skipped".

The control exists of a Image with a Textfield below it.

Before the control is being added to the canvas, it first has to be made.

**Question**

How can I change my program so the controls get added properly and the storyboard played without lag no mather how many controls I need to add?

Perhaps something with a ASync operation that creates the control?

Any ideas will be welcome but please if you send a idea, give a small example aswell.

MVVM Binding is not an option.

**Update**

Method to get new Element

```
        var control = new ElementControl(item);
        x = (x < 0) ? (GetWidth() * (i % GetCount())) : x;
        y = (y < 0) ? (GetHeight() * (i / GetCount())) : y;
        control.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x);
        control.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y);
        control.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, gbl.zIndex++);
        control.Drag_Completed += Element_Dropped;
        control.Drag_Started += Element_Dragging;
        control.DoubleClick += DoubleClick;
        return control;
```

basicly it's only this. The return control is being added to the canvas with "Canvasname.Children.Add"

In the control creation there are drag, drop and move events added to the control.

**Update 2**

Storyboard on the control

```
<Storyboard x:Name="FadeIn">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                              Value="0" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
                              Value="1" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Storyboard trigger in mainpage.xaml.cs

```
MainCanvas.Children.Where(m => m.GetType() == typeof(ElementControl)).ToList().ForEach(m => (m as ElementControl).FadeIn.Begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a control on another thread will just make you cry. It throws an error every time anything on the UI is created or otherwise touched by another thread. The creation of the control shouldnt take too much time so I doubt the problem is creation. You should be able to set an animation on an object that starts after a specified delay and runs automatically. The problem could also just be the inherent slowness of a browser plugin when 30 or 40 objects are animating at the same time.

Maybe you can post some code to help us see if you've overlooked something.

Comment: it looks like the control creation is not your problem, because that code should run faster than you can blink. I have a feeling the animation complexity is slowing down your plugin. How do you start the animation?

Comment: second update posted. Notice, I made it last for a second so the storyboard is in fact shown. I prefer it on .2 or .3 where it is shown but not annoyingly long since the control can't be used during the storyboard. However, in current settings, setting it to .2 it will just pop up without any fading at all (If there's more then about 25/30 controls).